# How to delete the contents of a file using C++

Tags: c++, file

I am making a program where I would like to check the first line of a .txt file for a specific string. If that string is tampered with or does not exist I would like to delete the content of the entire file to prevent tampering with the file. I know that it is possible to delete the contents of the file when opening it, but I cannot find a way to do so after checking the first line.

```
getline(infile, fLine);
cout<<fLine<<"\n";

if(fLine != "Line One"){
  infile.clear();
  outfile << "Line One\n";
  }
```

Comment: `ios::clear` does not do what you think it does.. Delete the file and recreate it.

Comment: [`std::ifstream::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write nothing to the file by truncating it:

```
infile.close()
infile.open("file.txt", fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
infile.close()
```

note that this implementation will depend on your declaration of infile. If it is an `ifstream` you will need to do this:

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("file.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc);
outfile.close()
```